# Updating local git branch before pushing

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I am working with my team on a project on bitbucket with git.

1. I first clone the repo. => **git clone**
2. I want to add a new file. => **git add**
3. I commit my new file => **git commit**
4. If I do a **git status**, I see my branch is one commit ahead.
5. Some members of my team have also made changes, but no link with my new file added.
   I update my project before submitting => **git pull origin master** => this automatically triggers a merge(?!)
6. If I do a **git status**, I see now my branch is ahead by 2 commits.
7. I push my changes => **git push origin master** => my 2 commits are pushed

What I don't understand is **why the git pull triggered a merge**? There was no need here.

All I wanted was to commit a new file, why do I have finally 2 commits?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you and your coworkers made changes of the same base. So they need to be merged. You could eliminate extra commit if you do rebase instead of merge. Rebase would have effect like if you would get your coworkers changes before your change and then applied yours.

Comment: ok, so you suggests next time to do a git rebase instead of a git pull, that's right?

Comment: pull is just a shortcut to fetch+merge. It can be changed to fetch+rebase. However, rebase will work well in your specific case but may become more complex in other cases. I, personally, prefer merge and see not much harm in extra commit. Definitelly don't rebase changes that are already pushed - it will cause trouble for your teammates.

Comment: For a small commit like this `git pull --rebase` should work great. Of course, rebasing can conflict just as merging and can be harder to fix. For adding large features e.g. from a topic branch it's generally better to merge and have a commit to show it's been integrated into the current branch.